# Do I need a current protection?

Tags: microcontroller, amplifier, circuit-protection, variable

I have a [variable gain amplifier](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/vca821.pdf?ts=1623509946663&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.de%252F) that can output a current of 90 mA. The output is directly connected to a µController I/O pin.

My question is: do I need something like over-current protection, since the VGA can output around 90 mA, or does the µController only take as much current as it needs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the I/O could be configured as an output (maybe accidentally or at startup) there might be a situation where you could damage the uC, depending on specs.

If it's an input only, and the output is always within the max voltage ratings of the input then you don't need any over current protection.  The input is likely relatively high impedance and will not draw large amounts of current.

Comment: I looked into the datasheet and the I/Os have a 50 ohm resistor infront of them. The VGAs maximum voltage output will be 3.5V,  50ohm /3.5V = 70mA. So it will draw 70mA, right?

Comment: @Yoomo No, if your I/O is configured as an input, the 50 ohms will be in series with a much larger impedance and you would not expect the input to draw much current.